# Exception thrown at 0x00007FF6021F251F in openmp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000000000F0. in open-mp

Tags: c++, openmp

I'm trying to use a parallel code in c++ program using open-MP.
this Code without openmp runs well.
I see this crash in line 65 and 66 when parallel code is solved .

Exception thrown at 0x00007FF6021F251F in openmp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int i, j, m;
double**** g, **** f;
int n = 50;
LARGE_INTEGER StartingTime, EndingTime, ElapsedMicroseconds;
LARGE_INTEGER Frequency;
int main()
{
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&Frequency);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&StartingTime);

    f = new double*** [n];
    g = new double*** [n];
    


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        f[i] = new double** [n];
        g[i] = new double** [n];

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {

            f[i][j] = new double* [n];
            g[i][j] = new double* [n];
            

            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                f[i][j][k] = new double[n];
                g[i][j][k] = new double[n];
            }

        }

    }

# pragma omp parallel
    {

        m = omp_get_num_procs();
        printf("number of processor= %d \n", m);
        m = omp_in_parallel();
        printf("if program in paralle=1 or serial=0 ?? %d \n", m);
        m = omp_get_max_threads();
        printf("muaximum number of thread= %d \n", m);
        m = omp_get_num_threads();
        printf("number of threads= %d \n", m);
        m = omp_get_thread_num();
        printf("thread number is= %d \n", m);

#pragma omp for schedule (static,10)
for(i=0 ; i <n ;i++)
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
            for(int a=0;a<n;a++)
        {
        f[i][j][a][k] = 1;
        g[i][j][a][k] = 2;
        }

    }

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&EndingTime);
    ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart = EndingTime.QuadPart - StartingTime.QuadPart;
    ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart *= 1000000000;
    ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart /= Frequency.QuadPart;
    cout << "time : " << ElapsedMicroseconds.QuadPart << endl;

}
```

Can you help me solve the problem?

Comment: I'd start with `double g[50][50][50][50], f[50][50][50][50];` plus getting rid of all those dynamic allocations. Make sure that this works, then move forward.

Comment: Being called a [three-star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) is *not* a compliment. You're a ***four***-star programmer. Please don't do that.

Comment: One problem of your code is that the `i`, `j`, and `k` variables are shared inside the parallel regions. You need private variables in `for` loops. Don't use global variables at all here. Declare the variables in `for (int i = ...` instead.

Comment: @goodvibration It might not be a good idea to put 100MB on the stack. This will give you an actual stack overflow.

Comment: That being said, this way of dynamically allocating an n>1 dimensional object is the worst way possible. You want to allocate all needed memory in one allocation per object (use std::vector for good style). Then use lexic indexing (f[i][j][a][k] should be translated to f[((i * n + j) * n + a) * n + k]). Ideally package this index calculation in a function or sth like that, i.e. f[idx(i,j,a,k)] .

Comment: @Paul: Can use the data section (global scope) then. Can also use a number smaller than 50 for this step of the investigation.

Comment: No idea what exactly you mean by data section. Keep in mind, that memory size grows very rapidly with n^4. n=10 for example still takes 80KB per object, which should be fine for the stack.

Comment: @Paul It means the data segment of the program. Global and static objects are not stored on the stack.

Comment: I actually didn't observe that he has this global data section (might be my own bias of almost never using (non constexpr) global variables). So yes you are right.

Comment: `j` should be private.